# I am trying to update multiple images but getting error using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update multiple images but unfortunately I am getting error please help me how can i resolved that ? thank u.

**please check error**

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

**controller**

```
       public function update(Request $request, $roomId)
         {
     
            if($request->has('images')){
                foreach($request->file('images')  as $value){
                    $extension = $value->getClientOriginalExtension();
                     Storage::disk('wfh')->put($value->getFilename() . '.' . $extension, 
                     File::get($value));

                     $roomDetail->image = $value->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;

                     $roomDetail = RoomDetail::where('room_id',$roomId)->first();

                    $roomDetail->update([
                        'room_id'  => $roomId,
                        'image' =>   $roomDetail->image,
                    ]);

                }

        }
```

**Html view**

```
      <form action="{{route('room.update',$editRooms->id)}}" method="POST" class="needs-validation" 
      novalidate  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <label class="active">Images Upload</label>
                    <div class="input-images" style="padding-top: .5rem;" ></div>

                    @foreach ($roomDetails as $value)
                    <img height="100px" class="mt-4 m-4" width="100px" src="{{ 
                      Config('wfh.file') 
                     .$value->image}}" alt="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="{{$value->image}}" >
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100">Add 
                 Room</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you have a hidden type field and you're trying to loop through files that aren't present !! There are no files !!

Comment: instead you can access the values like this ``foreach ( $request->images as $value )``

Comment: but then again you'll face errors as you're trying to access file property on non-file value.